# Tests failed while updated pytest-qt v3.1.0 fixture qtmodeltester.check explicitly testing string_types for DisplayRole

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

pytest-qt v3.1.0 explicitly testing string_types for DisplayRole of data. Which is not the case for older versions. It has broken our tests because we return object (int, str, etc.,) for DispalyRole of data which we think reasonable (aren't we?).

Could anyone please share if you know why it is the case?

Technologies:
Python 2.7.x x64 and Pyside v1.2.4
OS:
Windows 7 machine

```
def _test_data(self):
    """Test model's implementation of data()"""
    if not self._has_children():
        return

    # A valid index should have a valid QVariant data
    assert self._model.index(0, 0).isValid()

    string_types = [str]
    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        string_types.append(unicode)  # noqa
    if qt_api.QString is not None:
        string_types.append(qt_api.QString)

    string_types = tuple(string_types)

    types = [
        (qt_api.QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, string_types),
        (qt_api.QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole, string_types),
        (qt_api.QtCore.Qt.StatusTipRole, string_types),
        (qt_api.QtCore.Qt.WhatsThisRole, string_types),
        (qt_api.QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole, qt_api.QtCore.QSize),
        (qt_api.QtCore.Qt.FontRole, qt_api.QtGui.QFont),
        (
            qt_api.QtCore.Qt.BackgroundColorRole,
            (qt_api.QtGui.QColor, qt_api.QtGui.QBrush),
        ),
        (
            qt_api.QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole,
            (qt_api.QtGui.QColor, qt_api.QtGui.QBrush),
        ),
        (
            qt_api.QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole,
            (
                qt_api.QtGui.QPixmap,
                qt_api.QtGui.QImage,
                qt_api.QtGui.QIcon,
                qt_api.QtGui.QColor,
                qt_api.QtGui.QBrush,
            ),
        ),
    ]

    # General purpose roles with a fixed expected type
    for role, typ in types:
        data = self._model.data(self._model.index(0, 0), role)
        if data is not None:
            data = qt_api.extract_from_variant(data)

      assert data == None or isinstance(data, typ), role  # noqa
      AssertionError: PySide.QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole
      assert (1 == None or False)
      where False = isinstance(1, (<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>))
```

---

```
.tox\py27\lib\site-packages\pytestqt\modeltest.py:499: AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion from one of the `pytest-qt` maintainers:

The model tester is based on the Qt model tester (and was updated to its newest version with v1.3.0). That [does the same check](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v5.11.2/src/testlib/qabstractitemmodeltester.cpp#L585-L589), and Qt's documentation also [says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) (emphasis mine):

> Custom models should return data in these types.

and

> Qt::DisplayRole: The key data to be rendered in the form of text. (QString)

If you use that data for custom purposes (rather than displaying it), you should probably use Qt::UserRole.

IMHO, it's clear from Qt's tester and documentation that this isn't allowed.